# Copy and paste between Mac and Ubuntu using keyboard shortcuts via VMware Fusion

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, vmware, vmware-fusion, vmware-tools

I use OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and have VMware Fusion 7.1.1 where Ubuntu 14.04 has been installed. Moreover, I have installed [VMware Tools patches](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches).

Copy and paste between Mac and Ubuntu using keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) worked fine before. I don't know if it is because of the recent upgrade from VMware Fusion 6.x to 7.1.1 or the installation of the VMware Tools patches, but copy and paste does not work any more. Here are some screenshots of the settings:

[image]
[image]

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

First verify that "Enable Drag and Drop" and "Enable Copy and Paste" are enabled in the "Isolation" settings.

Then, execute the following commands in Ubuntu :

1. `sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools`
2. Install VMware Tools by following the usual method (Virtual Machine --> Reinstall VMWare Tools)
3. Reboot the VM
4. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`
5. Once again, reboot the VM, after the reboot copy/paste and drag/drop will work!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop` fixed it for me.

Comment: I can't get this to work with Fusion 12